# Classification for phrases like "slim chance" and "fat chance" that look like opposites but have the same meaning

Tags: meaning, phrases, antonyms, auto-antonyms

How is it that "slim chance" and "fat chance" have the same meaning? Is there a linguistic classification for this phenomenon of seemingly opposite phrases that have the same meaning?

Comment: _Slim chance_ is metaphorical -- _slim_ means little. _Fat chance_ is ironic, as the opposite of _slim_.

Comment: Similar to "a fat lot of good that will do you".

Answer (score 2):

As John Lawler observes in a comment above, "slim chance" directly describes the chance of occurrence of some future event that is not at all likely. *Slim* falls into line with *slight* and *little*, both of which are frequently used with *chance* to express the idea that the odds that a particular thing will happen are not good. From the expression "slim chance," we also get the lengthier descriptive phrase: "two chances—slim and none," sometimes with the additional flourish "and slim just left the building."

"Fat chance," meanwhile, uses *fat* in the opposite sense to its logical meaning of "large." Christine Ammer, *The Facts on File Dictionary of Clichés* (2006) has this entry for *fat chance*:

> **fat chance** Practically no chance at all. Although *fat* in this context means "good," the term is always used ironically to mean hardly any opportunity. A slangy Americanism of the twentieth century, it was used by P. G. Wodehouse in *Laughing Gas* [1936]: "A fat chance, of course. I should have known his psychology better."

In effect, "fat chance" and "slim chance" present the reverse case to auto-antonyms (words that can have opposite meanings, like *cleave*, *oversight*, and *sanction*); in this instance, the same meaning is attributed to seemingly opposite words or phrases.

Since there are so many category names for auto-antonyms—[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) lists *addad*, *antagonym*, *antilogy*, *contronym/contranym*, *enantiodrome*, *enantionymy*, *enantiosemy*, *Janus word*, and *self-antonym*—you'd think that some classification term for the reverse case must exist. But I haven't found any that appears to be in widespread use.

The author of the [Antagonyms](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~cellis/antagonym.html) webpage points out that the words *cool* and *hot* (as applied to something attractive) and the phrases "burned up" and "burned down" fit a similar pattern to "fat chance" and "slim chance." The same might be said of *inflammable* and *flammable* (both of which can mean capable of catching fire). The Antagonyms writer suggests that *opposonyms* or *pseudopposites* might be a good category name; but to judge from the few Google search matches that turn up, neither term appears to have gained much of a following in actual usage since 1999, when the page was last revised.